# Getting error when sending email through Java

Tags: java, email

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.util.logging.*;

import java.util.Properties;


    public class Hw1 {
        public static void SendingMal(String recepient) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("preparing to send");
        Properties pro = new Properties();
        
        pro.put("mail.stmp.auth","true");
        pro.put("mail.stmp.starttls.enable", "true");
        pro.put("mail.stmp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        pro.put("mail.stmp.port", "587");
        
        String myemail="from@gmail.com";
        String pass = "pass";
        
        Session sess= Session.getInstance(pro, new Authenticator(){
        
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(myemail, pass);
            
        }
        });
        
        Message mess = preporeMessage(sess,myemail,recepient);
        
        Transport.send(mess);
        System.out.print("Message sent succesfully");
        
        }
    
        private static Message preporeMessage(Session sess,String myemail, String recepient ) {
            
            try {
    
    
            Message mess = new MimeMessage(sess);
            mess.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myemail));
            mess.setRecipient (Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recepient));
            
            mess.setSubject("Hi there");
            mess.setText("Hey there,\n My frist email sending through Java");
    
            return mess;`enter code here`
            }
            
        catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Hw1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,e);
                
            }
            return null;
    
    }
    
    }
    
    
    public class SendingMail {
        
        
        `enter code here`public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {
        `enter code here`Hw1.SendingMal("to@gmail.com");
```

This is what I am getting:

preparing to send
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
at Hw1.preporeMessage(Hw1.java:49)
at Hw1.SendingMal(Hw1.java:37)
at SendMail.main(SendMail.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 3 more

Comment: Do you have any class named "SendMail.java"?

Comment: Please check whether your classPath is correct.
secondly check if the jar file is available. Mostly it will happen because of missing jar file.
If it is missing please download import it to the project from the below link.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0

Comment: I don't see anywhere to download from the link you provided

Comment: In that link you can the maven dependency . You can add that in your pom.xml and try